# How To Create Mongoose Schema with Array of Object IDs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have defined a mongoose user schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: { type: String, required: true},
  name: {
      first: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
      last: { type: String, required: true, trim: true}
  },
  phone: Number,
  lists: [listSchema],
  friends: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
  accessToken: { type: String } // Used for Remember Me
});

var listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    contents: [contentSchema],
    created: {type: Date, default:Date.now}
});
var contentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    quantity: String,
    complete: Boolean
});

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

the friends parameter is defined as an array of Object IDs.
So in other words, a user will have an array containing the IDs of other users. I am not sure if this is the proper notation for doing this.

I am trying to push a new Friend to the friend array of the current user:

```
user = req.user;
  console.log("adding friend to db");
  models.User.findOne({'email': req.params.email}, '_id', function(err, newFriend){
    models.User.findOne({'_id': user._id}, function(err, user){
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      user.friends.push(newFriend);
    });
  });
```

however this gives me the following error:

TypeError: Object 531975a04179b4200064daf0 has no method 'cast'

Answer (score 175):

If you want to use Mongoose populate feature, you should do:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: { type: String, required: true},
  name: {
      first: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
      last: { type: String, required: true, trim: true}
  },
  phone: Number,
  lists: [listSchema],
  friends: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  accessToken: { type: String } // Used for Remember Me
});
exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This way you can do this query:

```
var User = schemas.User;
User
 .find()
 .populate('friends')
 .exec(...)
```

You'll see that each User will have an array of Users (this user's friends).

And the correct way to insert is like Gabor said:

```
user.friends.push(newFriend._id);
```

Comment: But then it creates an array looking like `[{"$oid": "dfdfsdfsg565ls"},...]` instead of `["hkugh87tgkgk", ....]`

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be, a list of ObjectIds. Mongoose already handle them.

Comment: What does `populate()` do exactly?

Comment: @KennyWorden the populate method from mongoose simulate a join in traditional relational databases. So in this case the populate will replace the friends array with an array of Users documents.

Comment: Hey, @RodrigoReis can you tell me how to write query if i want to` name -> first = 'ajay';  `  I am roughly write this but not geting any result.

Comment: How to set default value to an empty array in this case?

Comment: @AlexZinkevych actually Mongoose already sets array types to [] as default, so you're good there.

Comment: If anybody is getting error in `objectid is not defined`, use `Schema.Types.ObjectId` d instead

Comment: If i want to add new variable such as `chatID` in each element in friends array, `friends: [{{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, chatId : ObjectId}]`, is that right ?

Answer (score 29):

I'm new to Mongoose myself, so I'm not entirely sure this is right. However, you appear to have written:

```
friends: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
```

I believe the property you're looking for is actually found here:

```
friends: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
```

It may be that the docs have changed since you posted this question though. Apologies if that's the case. Please see [the Mongoose SchemaTypes docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 9):

I would try this.

```
user.friends.push(newFriend._id);
```

or

```
friends: [userSchema],
```

but i'm not sure if this is correct.