# Mongoose schema for array of sub-documents ids from a different collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this for a family (whose children are enrolled in a school)...

```
var familySchema = new Schema({
    parents: [{
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        email: String,
    }],
    students: [{
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        grade: Number,
    }]
});
```

I'd like to describe many schools that contain classrooms, and have the classrooms contain students, something like this...

```
var schoolSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    street: String,
    classrooms: [{
        classroomNumber: Number,
        students: [ /* I am mixed up here */ ]
    }]
});
```

How do I tell mongoose that I want an array of object ids for students found in the other collection?

I understand [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25153874/294949) that, if I wanted the classrooms to refer to family documents, I could say something like:

```
families: { type : ObjectId, ref: 'Family' }
```

but how do I do the same for **sub**-documents of another collection? (If it isn't obvious, I'm just learning both mongo and mongoose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use sub-documents [reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), you need to change your reference to the `'student'` array.

```
var studentSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    grade: Number,
});

var familySchema = new Schema({
    parents: [{
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        email: String,
    }],
    students: [studentSchema]
});

var schoolSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    street: String,
    classrooms: [{
        classroomNumber: Number,
        students: [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Family.students' }]
    }]
});

var Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema );  
var Family = mongoose.model('Family ', familySchema ); 
var School = mongoose.model('School', schoolSchema );
```

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Hey - sorry to bother with a followup:  I'm following a pattern where I have one file per model, and each model file says `module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', ModelSchema);` at the end.  So, in my family.js, can I just call `mongoose.model('Student'...` on student and discard the result (so I can still export the family model)?  And, in my school.js, must I require any other model files to use the syntax you suggest?

Comment: @user1272965, in each model file, you can use `mongoose.model('Model', ModelSchema);`, when you want to use this model file in other file, you should use `var School = mongoose.model('School');`, then this `School` could be use in this file... Hope I make myself clearly.

Comment: Using above method, when i use populate() in find - it returns error as 'Schema hasn't registered for model "Family.students"'