# How to implement type:(new mongoose.Schema) as Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model for order in my nodejs Application and need to implement in it the number of products which will be in the order.

I have Added The Product type as (new mongoose.Schema) and validate it by Joi, in this case, I can Only add one Product

here is the model of order

```
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 50
  },  
  OrderDate: {
    type: Date,
    default : Date.now
  },
  Address: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 50,
    required: true,
  },
  City: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 50,
    required: true,
  },
  Phone: {
    type:Number,
    required: true
  },
  Payment: {
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
  OrderPrice: {
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
  ShippingPrice:{
    type:Number
  },
  customer: {
    type: new mongoose.Schema({
      UserName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
      },
      Email: {
        type: String,
        unique : true,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255
      },Phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min :10 
      },
      Address: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
      }
    }),  
    required: true
  },
  product:
     {
    type: new mongoose.Schema({
    Pro_Name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    Pro_Price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
      },
    Pro_IMG: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
      },
    // Pro_Qty: {
    //   type: Number,
    //   min: 1
    //   }
    }),
    require: true
  }

  }));
```

And The Joi validation :

```
function validateOrder(order) {
    const schema = {
      Name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
      Address: Joi.string().required(),
      City: Joi.string().required(),
      Phone: Joi.number().required(),
      Payment: Joi.string().required(),
      OrderPrice: Joi.number().required(),
      customerID:Joi.objectId(),
      productID:Joi.objectId(),

    };

    return Joi.validate(order, schema);
  }
```

Also the rout for creating the order

```
router.post('/', async(req, res)=>{     
    const {error} = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(404).send(error.details[0].message);

    const customer = await Customer.findById(req.body.customerID);
    if (!customer) return res.status(400).send('Invalid customer Pleas Login First.');

    const product = await Product.findById(req.body.productID);
    if (!product) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Product to be add in the cart');

    //create the new Product
    let newOrder = new Order({ 
        Name: req.body.Name,
        Address: req.body.Address,
        City: req.body.City,
        Phone: req.body.Phone,
        Payment: req.body.Payment,
        OrderPrice: req.body.OrderPrice,
        customer: {
            _id: customer.id,
            UserName: customer.UserName,
            Email:customer.Email,
            Phone:customer.Phone,
            Address:customer.Address
        },
        product: {
            _id: product.id,
            Pro_Name: product.Pro_Name,
            Pro_Price:product.Pro_Price,
            Pro_IMG:product.Pro_IMG
        }
    });

    // try{
    //     new Fawn.Task()
    //       .save('orders' , newOrder)
    //       .update('product' , {_id:Product._id},{
    //         $inc: {numberInStock : -1 }
    //       })
    //       .run();
    //     res.send(newOrder);
    //   }
    //    catch(ex){
    //      res.status(500).send('Somthing bad has happend -_-.')
    //    }


    newOrder = await newOrder.save();

    res.send(newOrder);
});
```

When I Try My Code by Postman The Input

```
{
    "Name": "Hend Mohammed",
    "Address": "This is Forth adress",
    "City": "Giza",
    "Phone": 12345689,
    "Payment": "By HEND ^_^ With products and data a bout the customer",
    "OrderPrice": 50000,
    "customerID":"5cb18f625a9de34582475b22",
    "productID" :"5ca11d5f9456812c79d21be6"
}
```

and The output  like

```
{
    "_id": "5cb1a3b7c05d72523925bbac",
    "Name": "Hend Mohammed",
    "Address": "This is Forth adress",
    "City": "Giza",
    "Phone": 12345689,
    "Payment": "By HEND ^_^ With products and data a bout the customer",
    "OrderPrice": "50000",
    "customer": {
        "_id": "5cb18f625a9de34582475b22",
        "UserName": "heba Mohammed",
        "Email": "hebs47852@gmail.com",
        "Phone": 12345678910,
        "Address": "1235Adress"
    },
    "product": {
        "_id": "5ca11d5f9456812c79d21be6",
        "Pro_Name": "Cake updated",
        "Pro_Price": 100,
        "Pro_IMG": "Cake Image"
    },
    "OrderDate": "2019-04-13T08:54:15.994Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This Give me permission to add one product But I need To add more than one product in the Order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define like this, create new `object` schema `productSchema`

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Pro_Name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    Pro_Price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
      },
    Pro_IMG: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
      }
});
```

Assign this scheme into your `orderschema` to `product`.

```
const model = new mongoose.Schema({
  Product: [productSchema] <-- it will be as a array of objects
});
const Order = mongoose.model("Order", model);
```

Product then will act as a Array of object to store multiple products.

Comment: can you give me more explanation I didn't understand

Comment: @hend i have updated my answers, let me know if you still don't get what i am trying to suggest.

Comment: @hend did you got it, what I was suggesting?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your asking and sorry for my delay in replay I have made the changes as you have mentioned before but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I think there is a better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25153874/861712